# How to create an Action from another with an additional parameter?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a class available in the .Net Framework which wraps an Action and another parameter just like EnhancedAction in the following example?

```
private void Test(string s)
{
  // I would like :
  // Method1(EnhancedAction.Create(Method2, s));

  // But I must write :
  Method1(i => Method2(i, s));
}

private void Method1(Action<int> myAction)
{
  myAction(1);
}

private void Method2(int i, string s)
{

}
```

Comment: Is the lambda solution not easier than your proposed alternative?

Comment: With the alternative approach, you can imagine using Extension methods allowing a neat syntax like : action.WithAdditionalParam(s)

Comment: As a reader of this code, I would *still* prefer seeing the lambda to that method call.  It is much clearer to me what's going on.  For that method call it is not obvious to the reader which parameter is being replaced, for example, in addition to not really saving on space.

Answer (score 2):

You've already shown how to write the code; you merely need to create your own class that has that exact solution to implement the method you're asking for:

```
class EnhancedAction
{
    public static Action<T1> Create<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> action, T2 parameter2)
    {
        return parameter1 => action(parameter1 , parameter2);
    }
}
```

Although I fail to see how this is easier to write out than just using the lambda directly.

Comment: I am disapointed, there is no such tool in the framework or in any opensource third-party lib? (I would have prefered to avoid writing it)

Comment: @RomainHautefeuille Why would the framework or an open source third party library need to write a one line method that is trivially simple to implement for you?  If you need it, you can write it yourself.  And as I described in comments to your question, I don't see this as being useful; if you want to use it, go right ahead, it's super easy to write, but I don't see value added here.

Comment: Because such tools exist in other langages (e.g. c++ Boost Bind)? Because if I want to deal with Action<T1, T2, T3> I need to write it once again? Because it would be cool to make it a standard for everyone? Plus I don't think your point of being a one line method is acceptable : Enumerable.AsEnumerable() is also a one line method but it is included in the Framework.

Comment: I admit Method1(EnhancedAction.Create(Method2, s)); or even action.WithAdditionalParam(s) is not a perfect syntax though. But with static import in C#6 it can be reduced to : Method1(Bind(Method2, s)). It maps to the well known Boost syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I found Umbrella which provides what I was looking for : http://umbrella.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Src/Umbrella/Binding/CurryExtensions.cs

Though it doesn't seem very active lately.